# Remove background from radio button on unCheck

Tags: jquery, radio-button, checked

Code and Demo: http://spotsync.com/res.net/portals/reo/snippets/radio.html

I'm trying to add a green background to a radio button and/or checkbox on its checked state.

The checkbox works properly, but when a different radio button is checked, its background color is not removed. What am I missing here?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964961/jquery-radio-onchange-toggle-class-of-parent-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i know how to solve it ill give u a fiddle in a minute :-)

This works perrfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/CujPG/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var children = $('.greenBG').children('input:not(:checked)'); 

            if(children.length > 0){
                $(children).each(function(){
                    $(this).parent().removeClass('greenBG');
                })
            }
            $(this).parent().addClass('greenBG');
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry for the delay. that is the reason for the `-1`'s

Answer (score 1):

When you are working with radios, you work with a group of inputs, so you cannot just use `this is checked` condition. You need to filter for the group.

**Check it out here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/PCkXS/

Comment: Thanks for that. I used a combination of your answer and Gary's below to solve the problem. Basically I wasn't aware you could step down and back a Dom selection with jQuery.

Comment: Glad i helped, javascript can do a lot of things indeed

Answer (score 1):

Remember to add `name=` to the checkbox and this will work nicely

```
$('input').change(function() {
   $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').parent().removeClass('greenBG')
   .find(':checked').parent().addClass('greenBG');
});
```