# Change class of parent div if radio input checked

Tags: javascript, html, loops, radio-button, checked

I've been searching and searching google for answers to my question but have been unsuccessful so far. I'm hoping one of you guys could give me some assistance.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/stevenschemers/72tp7/7/) is published [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/stevenschemers/72tp7/7/).

My goal is to have the table containing the selected radio button className be change to "selected" when the radio is selected, and "container" when the radio is not selected.

I have 10 divs with the class name "dividend" holding a table with the className of "container" then two smaller tables inside that. Within the container table at the bottom is a hidden radio button with the name "page1". Then another 10 of the same but the input names are "page2"

I wrote an onClcick for the container table so the user can select the whole table instead of the radio button, but not I'm trying to change the style of the selected container so the users know they have selected it.

I have tried a few different methods and I'm able to change the style to the new class by just writing

```
 document.getElementById('container').className = 'selected';
```

But because all 10 divs share the same name it will only change the style of the first element it finds.

So I tried writing this loop to check if there are any selected radios in the document then to change the else name the style as the default.

I'm sure its something stupid but I'm pretty stumped atm.. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
//check for check = true
selected = function () {
var divs = document.getElementByTagName('DIV'),
    div,
    tbl = divs.getElementById('TABLE'),
    rad,
    stat,
    i;

    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
// no .id but the counter of the loop
div = div[i];
// check the className not the div element
if (div.className == 'dividend') {

    rad = tbl.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');

    if (tbl.className == 'container') {
    if (rad[0].checked == true) {
        tbl.className = 'selected'; 
    } 
}
}
}
};


// Gets radio button for selected element in Page1 and checks
function P1sClick(n){ 
document.forms["myform"]["page1"][n].checked=true;
selected();
};

// Gets radio button for selected element in Page2 and checks
function P2sClick(n){ 
 document.forms["myform"]["page2"][n].checked=true;

};

////////////HTML  I only included 2 examples of the DIVs because its a lot of code/////

<form name="myform" action="sample.asp" method="POST">

<h2>Page 1</h2>

<div class="dividend>
<table class="container" onclick="P1sClick(0)" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td valign="top" >
  <table class="grid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td width="40" height="25" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000; border-    right:1px solid #000;">1</td></tr>
    <tr><td height="25" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000; border-right:1px solid #000;">2</td></tr>
    <tr><td height="25" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000; border-right:1px solid #000;">3</td></tr>
    <tr><td height="25" style="border-right:1px solid #000;">4</td></tr>
  </table>
</td><td valign="top">
  <table class="grid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td width="40" height="25" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;">5</td></tr>
    <tr><td height="25" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;">6</td></tr>
    <tr><td height="25" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;">7</td></tr>
    <tr><td height="25">8</td></tr>
  </table>
</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center" height="20" style="padding-top:3px; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;">4x4<br><input type="radio" name="page1" title="4 by 4" value="4x4" style="display:none;"></td></tr></table>
</div>

<div class="dividend">
<table class="container" onclick="P2sClick(0)" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td valign="top">
      <table class="grid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td width="40" height="25" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000; border-right:1px solid #000;">1</td></tr>
    <tr><td height="25" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000; border-right:1px solid #000;">2</td></tr>
    <tr><td height="25" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000; border-right:1px solid #000;">3</td></tr>
    <tr><td height="25" style="border-right:1px solid #000;">4</td></tr>
  </table>
</td><td valign="top">
  <table class="grid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td width="40" height="33" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;">5</td></tr>
    <tr><td height="33" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;">6</td></tr>
    <tr><td height="34">7</td></tr>
  </table>
</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center" height="20" style="padding-top:3px; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;">4x3<br><input type="radio" name="page2" title="4 by 3" value="4x3" style="display:none;"></td></tr></table>
    </div>
```

UPDATE:

So I've been looking into jQuery and found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964961/jquery-radio-onchange-toggle-class-of-parent-element) post here. I'm trying out this function which looks like it should work to me, but isn't. Maybe you can tell me if this is a better route to go..

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('input[type="radio"]').change( function() {
  //   grab all the radio buttons with the same name as the one just changed
    var this_radio_set = $('input[name="'+$(this).attr("page1")+'"]');

    // iterate through each  
//     if checked, set its parent label's class to "selected"
//     if not checked, remove the "selected" class from the parent label
//     my HTML markup for each button is  <label><input type="radio" /> Label Text</label>
//     so that this works anywhere even without a unique ID applied to the button and label
    for (var i=0; i < this_radio_set.length;i++) {
    if ( $(this_radio_set[i]).is(':checked') )             $(this_radio_set[i]).parent('table').addClass('selected');
        else $(this_radio_set[i]).parent('table').removeClass('selected');
}
});
});
```

**UPDATE** I have updated my jQuery with the following corrections made by BobS. I'm now using jQuery to select the radio with the click of the table, and jquery to change the style when the radio is checked. For some reason I'm having trouble combining these two functions, so when you click the table and the radio is checked, then the style changes as well. Heres my latest code, hopefully someone can help me with this :p

```
// jQuery to select radio button within clicked table
$(function() {

$('table').click(function(event) {  

    if(event.target.type != "radio") {

        var that = $(this).find('input:radio');
        that.attr('checked', !that.is(':checked'));

    }
});
});

// jQuery to change the style of the table containing the selected radio button
$(function() {
$('input[type="radio"]').change( function() {
  //   grab all the radio buttons with the same name as the one just changed
    var this_radio_set = $('input[name="'+$(this).attr("name")+'"]');

    for (var i=0; i < this_radio_set.length;i++) {
    if ( $(this_radio_set[i]).is(':checked') )         
      $(this_radio_set[i]).closest('table').addClass('selected');
        else 
        $(this_radio_set[i]).closest('table').removeClass('selected');
}
});
});
```

Comment: You should edit your question and add the tag corresponding to the language you are using to get better answers quicker.

Comment: This example shows you're reusing IDs, do not do this, it isn't valid HTML. Use the class multiple times by all means.

Comment: Sorry I was in the process of editing it right after I submitted, the code is up now

Comment: So should I search for the className instead of the ID? I recently added the ID's to see if that would work..

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out what you're trying to achieve from the description I'm afraid. If you could create a jsfiddle for it, I'd be happy to take a look and see if I can unbend it. This entire exercise would be way easier in jQuery by the way.

Comment: I'm all for jQuery, I just dont know a whole lot more about it than I do JS, if you have any recommendations I'm open for any suggestions. Seems like the more I do in JS lately I'm hearing jQuery would be better instead lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things that may help you:

You seem to have dropped the id's for your elements in your recent edits.  This is fine, but you'll then have to loop through stuff.  You also should not expect getElementById to return elements based on the class in the element; that only applies to id's.

However, your "container" table in this case is always an immediate child of the "dividend" div, so you can use techniques such as

```
tbl=div.childNodes[0];
```

to get the table.

Be careful about class name comparison: if an element has more than one class name (acquired through inheritance), it may look like "fooclass dividend", and then your string comparison using == will not work.  Use a regex or string splitting for this.

I would also like to reiterate what everyone else is saying: stop what you're doing and learn jQuery :-)

UPDATE after xxstevenxo provided some jQuery code:

I did 3 things to get your new jQuery code to do something like what you want:

1. I got rid of the definition of the "selected" function, since it had a number of errors that was making the script exit before it hit your sample jQuery code.  Maybe you weren't having that problem -- depends on the sum total of what your JavaScript looked like.
2. When you refer to
   $(this).attr("page1")
   that should actually be
   $(this).attr("name")
   which will give you "page1" if you click the radio button for page1
3. Used "closest" instead of "parent".  parent only goes up one level, and the "table" selector only serves to filter based on whether the immediate parent is or is not a table.  closest continues up the tree until it finds a match.

Once I made those 3 changes, the jQuery was doing something close to what you had in mind, at least when the radio button is clicked.

You should probably take that anonymous function in your "change" action and use it in place of your "selected" function so that the style change would also take effect when the user clicks on the table.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did try to get both the childNode of the dividend and/or the parentNode of the actual input but had no luck when i did. Anytime I deal with loops it seems like they get the best of me. Do you know of any good jQuery tutorials/examples for something like this?

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at the jQuery I posted and tell me if this is a good way of going about this?

Comment: Yes thank you so much BobS! I made the corrections you recommended and now the style changes just as I had hoped. :D I see what you're saying where it only changes if the actual radio is clicked. I tried writing the same function in my selected function in my JS but that obviously didn't work lol.. How do I go about using this jQuery function in my JS function that selected the radio when the table is clicked?

Comment: I got it half working now. I posted it on jsfiddle for you to see.
Right now I can click the tables and the style will change along with the radio, but when I selecte another table the style on the previous one doesnt change back.. Can you please take a look at my function to see what I did wrong? Heres what I'm working on.  http://jsfiddle.net/stevenschemers/cGTYm/2/

Comment: I was able to get the style to add and remove based on the clicking of the table, but I can't seem to get the style to remove when another radio with the same name is checked.. :| heres a link to my latest jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/stevenschemers/cGTYm/20/

Answer (score 0):

first of all for best practices you should use a different id for elements. 
id is unique

second this is a mistake:
if (rad.checked = true) {

it should be with a ==
not just one =

Answer (score 0):

I hope I found all of your errors. X)

```
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    // no .id but the counter of the loop
    div = divs[i];
    // check the className not the div element
    if (div.className == 'dividend') {
        // Next will not work, because you would need divs 
        // with duplicate ids! Use classes instead.
        tbl = div.getElementById('container');
        // getElement>s<ByTagName
        rad = tbl.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
        // == not =
        if (rad[0].checked == true) {
            tbl.className = 'selected'; 
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried the corrections you made to the loop but was sill without any result. :\  I'm hoping to not have to make unique ID's for each table so my script can be a little more efficient. Is it possible to check all the inputs on the page to see if they are checked or not?

Comment: I think, it makes no sense to write the whole javascript and test it in all browsers. Did you ever consider using jQuery or a similar library?

Comment: I don't really know jQuery so I wouldn't even know where to begin.. If you know of any good tutorials for this kind of thing or if you wouldn't mind giving me an example here that would be awesome :D